# Where is Settings.settings stored? Can´t find it in app.config?

Tags: winforms, configuration, settings, settings.settings

**Hi,**

I have stored a couple of settings in my Settings.setting file(winform application) and I can see in the App.config that most of them is saved here under applicationSettings and userSettings.

There is however one applicationSetting that do not exists? I have also checked C:\Users[username]\AppData[ApplicationName] Local(windows7) but the setting is not there?

Could I add it manually to the app.config like this :

```
<applicationSettings>
    <MyApp.Client.Main.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="MySetting" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\temp</value>
      </setting>
    </MyApp.Client.Main.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Will this work?

Edit1:

This is how the Settings.Designer.cs looks like :

```
    [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("c:\\")]
    public string MySetting {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["MySetting"]));
        }
    }
```

This is my userSEttings part in app.config :

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <Orbit.Client.Main.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="MySetting23" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="MySetting24" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="MySetting25" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="MySetting26" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
    </Orbit.Client.Main.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <userSettings>
    <Orbit.Client.Main.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="MySetting49" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="MySetting49" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="MySetting48" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="MySetting47" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="MySetting46" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SkinName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Blue</value>
      </setting>
    </Orbit.Client.Main.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
```

Comment: A blog about these two : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/06/29/433979.aspx

Comment: I dont see how it helps, I have already checked the AppData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it happen to be a connection string? These are not stored in the `applicationSettings` section. Otherwise, it is not possible to have application settings that are not stored in the `ApplicationSettings` section. Could be your `app.config` is out of sync. Recompile your project.

Comment: No, its not a connection string and im sure that its in the Settings.settings but not in the app.config (same project)